# duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix when adding cordova file plugin to existing ios project

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an existing ios project and I want to use a cordova web view (with plugins). I've followed the [instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews) in the phonegap docs and my project successfully compiles.

However, when I want to add the file plugin to my project, I get the following error:

```
Ld /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.app/appworks-ios normal i386
cd /Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/workspace/appworks-ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/appworks-ios.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lGcmLib -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-CocoaLumberjack -lPods-ZipArchive -lProtocolBuffers -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lGcmLib -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-CocoaLumberjack -lPods-ZipArchive -lProtocolBuffers -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.3 /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -framework AssetsLibrary -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/appworks-ios_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.app/appworks-ios

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVFile.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVFile.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVLocalFilesystem.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
    /Users/jibrahim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appworks-ios-bvhgmyzzslupqsbrfkdduticdqik/Build/Intermediates/appworks-ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appworks-ios.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVLocalFilesystem.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's odd about this though is that every other plugin I have added successfully compiles (CDVSplashScreen for instance). This problem only occurs when I add CDVFile.m, CDVLocalFilesystem.m, and CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m to my project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 44):

Click on your Project Navigator from XCode.

Click on BuildSettings from it.

Find ***No Common Blocks*** in it and set it to No.

It works for me.

Comment: Fixed the very same problem for me with XCode 8, with Cordova managed by Ionic Framework (cli 2, project is on Ionic 1).

Comment: Worked for me also - XCode 12. iOS 14.

Answer (score 5):

same issue occurred recently, even using cocoaPods

solved by, in CDVFile.h

change

```
NSString* const kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix;
```

to

```
extern NSString* const kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't you how or if you solved it but I ran into the same problem and solved it by simply replacing every occurrence with @"cdvfile".